# NodeJS Stream with many producers and 1 consumer

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, ecmascript-6, pipe

I read some about `streams` in `Node.JS`.
I would like to have a stream that I can produce data from many `http` connections or local file read-streams and I want to be able to consume this data by one handler.

How can I do that?

Basically, I would like to do the following:

```
let stream = require('stream').Duplex;
let fs = require('fs');
let readline = require('readline');

const mainStream = new stream();

// here mainStream is used as ReadStream
const lineReader = readline.createInterface({input: mainStream});
lineReader.on('line', console.log);

// here mainStream is used as a writeStream
fs.createReadStream('./file1').pipe(mainStream);
fs.createReadStream('./file2').pipe(mainStream);
fs.createReadStream('./file3').pipe(mainStream);
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: So you would expect all your stream to babble jumbled, arbitrarily interleaved data? Why, what is the actual use case?

Comment: I have a lot of `JSON`s saved across multiple files, locally and on cloud storages.

I would like to process all of them.
Each line is a single object.

Comment: Then you'll need a separate `lineReader` for each of those files. Only then feed all of the lines into the same processing function.

Comment: Yes... there are many ways to approach this.
Yet, I'm still looking for an answer to my original question.

Comment: Actually I guess it could work out of the box to pipe multiple sources into the same destination. Have you tried it?

Comment: Of course :) it did not work... I've used this pattern on one way streams and it worked great.

Comment: What did happen? As I said, it doesn't work because lines are mixed up between files, but in principle it should work.